# C++ algorithm to find 'maximal difference' in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory

I am asking for your ideas regarding this problem:

I have one array A, with N elements of type `double` (or alternatively integer). I would like to find an algorithm with complexity less than O(N<sup>2</sup>) to find:

```
    max A[i] - A[j]
```

For 1 < j <= i < n. Please notice that there is no `abs()`. I thought of:

- dynamic programming
- dichotomic method, divide and conquer
- some treatment after a sort keeping track of indices

Would you have some comments or ideas? Could you point at some good ref to train or make progress to solve such algorithm questions?

Comment: What's the problem with just finding the maximum, finding the minimum, and then subtracting them? O(n) complexity. (I am sure I must be missing something in the question.)

Comment: If you aren't missing anything, the proper functions are `std::max_element` and `std::min_element` respectively.

Comment: @chris: Why not [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)?

Comment: @Blastfurnace, because I didn't know that existed O_o That saves the problem of having to go through twice to get both with standard functions. I see no reason not to use it now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make three sweeps through the array. First from `j=2` up, filling an auxiliary array `a` with *minimal* element so far. Then, do the sweep from the top `i=n-1` down, filling (also from the top down) another auxiliary array, `b`, with *maximal* element so far (from the top). Now do the sweep of the both auxiliary arrays, looking for a maximal difference of `b[i]-a[i]`.

That will be the answer. `O(n)` in total. You could say it's a dynamic programming algorithm.

***edit:*** As an optimization, you can eliminate the third sweep and the second array, and find the answer in the second sweep by maintaining two loop variables, *max-so-far-from-the-top* and *max-difference*.

As for "pointers" about how to solve such problems in general, you usually try some general methods just like you wrote - divide and conquer, memoization/dynamic programming, etc. First of all look closely at your problem and concepts involved. Here, it's maximum/minimum. Take these concepts apart and see how these parts combine in the context of the problem, possibly changing order in which they're calculated. Another one is looking for hidden order/symmetries in your problem.

Specifically, fixing an *arbitrary* inner point `k` along the list, this problem is reduced to finding the difference between the minimal element among all `j`s such that `1<j<=k`, and the maximal element among `i`s: `k<=i<n`. You see divide-and-conquer here, as well as taking apart the concepts of max/min (i.e. their *progressive* calculation), and the interaction between the parts. The hidden order is revealed (`k` goes along the array), and memoization helps save the interim results for max/min values.

The fixing of arbitrary point `k` could be seen as solving a smaller sub-problem first ("for a given `k`..."), and seeing whether there is anything special about it and it can be abolished - *generalized* - *abstracted* over.

There is a technique of trying to formulate and solve a bigger problem first, such that an original problem is a part of this bigger one. Here, we think of find *all* the differences for each k, and then finding the maximal one from them.

The *double use* for interim results (used both in comparison for specific `k` point, and in calculating the *next* interim result each in its direction) usually mean some considerable savings. So,

- divide-and-conquer
- memoization / dynamic programing
- hidden order / symmetries
- taking concepts apart - seeing how the parts combine
- double use - find parts with double use and memoize them
- solving a bigger problem
- trying arbitrary sub-problem and abstracting over it

Comment: Ok, now I see. I didn't see the full requirement. +1

Comment: @LuchianGrigore the OP added crucial requirement *after* you've posted your answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Don't be too hard on the OP, he typed `1 < j <= i < n` in the first revision, it just didn't show because it wasn't enclosed in backticks. Formatting fail, not meanness.

Answer (score 4):

This should be possible in a single iteration. `max(a[i] - a[j])` for 1 < j <= i should be the same as `max[i=2..n](a[i] - min[j=2..i](a[j]))`, right? So you'd have to keep track of the smallest `a[j]` while iterating over the array, looking for the largest `a[i] - min(a[j])`. That way you only have one iteration and j will be less than or equal to i.

Answer (score 1):

You just need go over the array find the max and min then get the difference, so the worst case is linear time . If the array is sorted, you can find the diff in constant time, or do I miss something?

Comment: the OP added crucial requirement after you've posted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Java implementation runs in linear time

```
public class MaxDiference {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(betweenTwoElements(2, 3, 10, 6, 4, 8, 1));
}

private static int betweenTwoElements(int... nums) {
    int maxDifference   = nums[1] - nums[0];
    int minElement      = nums[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] - minElement > maxDifference) {
            maxDifference = nums[i] - minElement;
        }
        if (nums[i] < minElement) {
            minElement =  nums[i];
        }           
    }       
    return maxDifference;
}
}
```