# find the maximal difference between all succeeding elements

Tags: performance, algorithm, haskell

I am trying to solve a training exercise I found at codeingame.com

The question is the following: You have a list of numbers and want to find minimal value for the differences between `v_small - v_big` , with the condition that `v_big > v_small` and `v_big` is **before** `v_small` in the list. In addition the maximal time for this question is 1 second, and maximal memory usage is 512MB.

For small lists a naive algorithm sufficient:

```
---------------------------------- try1.hs -------------------------------------
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))

main :: IO ()
main = do _ <- getLine
          v <- g . f . map read . take 1000 . words <$> getLine --or equivalently
--        v <- g . h . map read . take 1000 . words <$> getLine 
          print v

f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f [] =   []
f xx@(x:xs) = (minimum $ map (\y -> y-x) xx) : (f xs)

g :: [Int] -> Int
g [] = 0
g xs = minimum xs

h :: [Int] -> [Int]
h [] = []
h (x:xs) = (foldr (\y' y -> min (y'-x) y) 0 xs): (h xs)
```

But I think both functions `f` and `h` generate `n*(n+1)/2` many elements, where `n` is the length of the list. Which takes ages for the last list has 99999 many elements.

the next try was finding local maxima and minima and compare only maxima with minima - which should reduce the cost of the algorithm to #maxima*#minima

```
---------------------------------- try2.hs -------------------------------------
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
-- import Control.Arrow ((&&&))

data Extremum = Max Int | Min Int deriving (Show)


main :: IO ()
main = do _ <- getLine
          e <- getExtremes
          print e

getExtremes :: IO Int
getExtremes = minimum . concat . myMap f . headextr .
                                         map read . take 1000 .words <$> getLine

myMap :: (a -> [a] -> [b]) -> [a] -> [[b]]
myMap _ [] = []
myMap g xx@(x:xs) = (g x) xx : myMap g xs

f :: Extremum -> [Extremum] -> [Int]
f (Max y) (Max _:xs) = f (Max y) xs
f (Max y) (Min x:xs) = (min 0 (x-y)): f (Max y) xs
f _ _ = []

headextr :: [Int] -> [Extremum]
headextr xx@(x:y:_) | x > y = Max x : extremes xx
                    | x < y = Min x : extremes xx
headextr xx = extremes xx


extremes :: [Int] -> [Extremum]
extremes [] = []
extremes [x] = [Max x, Min x]
extremes [x,y]      | x > y          =       Min y:[]
                    | otherwise      =       Max y:[]
extremes (x:y:z:xs) | x > y && y < z = Min y:extremes (y:z:xs)
                    | x < y && y > z = Max y:extremes (y:z:xs)
                    | otherwise      =       extremes (y:z:xs)
```

But still the desired time of 1 second is not met.
I reduced the input with `take 1000` for profiling, but as I am not a professional programmer I was not able to make any use of it, the only information I found out - which quite obvious - in the first versions `f/h` are the costly functions and in the second version `f` too is the culprit.

the input file for this exercise can be found at http://www.codingame.com/ide/fileservlet?id=372552140039 - (if this link is not working it can be found at www.codingame.com -> training -> Stock exchange losses -> Test_5_input.txt/Test_5_output.txt)

So how to speed up this algorithm or is there another algorithm that is faster?

Comment: Which of the following are you looking for? The smallest distance between `v_small` and `v_big`, which is a minimum of `abs(v_small - v_big)`, which is the same as minimizing `v_big - v_small`. Or the largest distance between `v_small` and `v_big`, which is a minimum of `v_small - v_big`, which is the same as maximizing `v_big - v_small`.

Comment: Have you consider using vectors? List are normally slow, and since you have the condition index_vbig < index_vsmall, you could search vbig starting from the beginning of the vector and small from the end. This should give you the answer in a single pass.

Comment: I am looking for the latter minimum of `v_small - v_big`

Comment: I wonder what you think of this function. `f xs = maximum $ zipWith (-) (scanl1 max xs) xs`

Comment: @DanielWagner I think you should elaborate a bit why it is so fast? and secondly I think I should learn more haskell! and thirdly why are my versions so slow - especially the last one?

Comment: @DanielWagner your function is very elegant, but doesn't solve the problem precisely. The latter pair of maximum different values is needed. Bidirectionally traversable data structure should be used.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793048/c-algorithm-to-find-maximal-difference-in-an-array and use `Data.Vector`.

Comment: @leventov Can you give a sample input which my function does not work on? I'm not sure I understood your explanation of why it's wrong.

Comment: @DanielWagner your function works if the answer is the difference itself. But in this case why epsilonhalbe is writing about "the latter minimum"? I can't open the problem definition

Comment: @leventov I believe "the latter minimum" is in response to Cirdec's question, which offers two choices. epsilonhalbe wants the latter of those two choices.

Comment: `maximumBy` a comparison of tuples, using `zip` instead of `zipWith (-)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first two solutions are slow because for each element in the list, they do a computation that visits all successive elements. This is O(n^2). I haven't entirely grokked your second solution, but it seems to be something like this: filter out only local extrema (where local extremum means it's bigger than its two neighbors or smaller than its two neighbors), then run an O(n^2) algorithm on the list of extrema. Unfortunately, in the worst case every element can be an extremum, so this is also O(n^2) overall. (In fact, in a random list, we expect most elements to be local extrema, so this is not just being pessimistic about things.)

Let's see if we can invent an O(n) algorithm instead.

We'll start with a slightly rephrased O(n^2) algorithm. The idea of this algorithm is this: First, nondeterministically choose a place in the list to act as `v_big`. Then, nondeterministically choose a later place in the list to act as `v_small`. Take the maximal value among all these nondeterministic choices. In code:

```
f_spec xs = maximum $ do
    later@(v_big:_) <- tails xs
    v_small:_       <- tails later
    return (v_big - v_small)
```

Now, we need two separate insights to turn this into an O(n) algorithm. The first is that we only need to split once: once we have chosen `v_small`, we know that the right way to choose `v_big` is to pick the biggest element before it in the list. We can implement that algorithm this way:

```
f_slow xs = maximum $ do
    earlier@(v_small:_) <- tails (reverse xs)
    let v_big = maximum earlier
    return (v_big - v_small)
```

This is "almost" O(n): it only makes one nondeterministic choice; but doing the necessary computation once we've made that choice is still O(n), resulting in a total runtime of O(n^2). The second insight is that we can memoize the computation needed after our nondeterministic choice, so that this computation is O(1). We can build a list of all the maximums very efficiently like this:

```
maximums xs = scanl1 max xs
```

Like `maximum`, this function takes O(n) time; unlike `maximum`, this one returns the maximums of all prefixes of `xs` instead of just the maximum of the entire list. So now, when we do our nondeterministic choice, we can choose *both* `v_small` and `v_big` at the same time:

```
f_fast xs = maximum $ do
    (v_big, v_small) <- zip (maximums xs) xs
    return (v_big - v_small)
```

From there you only need a bit of prettification to get something that looks very pretty indeed and still runs in O(n) time:

```
f xs = maximum $ zipWith (-) (maximums xs) xs
```

Comment: Style of "Functional Programming Pearls"? Nice :)

Comment: Very nice and elegant solution.

Comment: I have now read this answer three times and even though I consider myself not a beginner of haskell anymore, I would not ever have come up with that solution. One reason is that I have not used scans a lot - which will definitely change. Thanks a very lot for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a `Monoid`, `BiggestDrop` that keeps track of the biggest drop across numbers. It remembers a third piece of information, the minimum in a range of numbers. This would allow us to split the dataset into pieces, process those pieces, and then combine the pieces to get the answer. The example code below doesn't take advantage of this; it merely folds the `Monoid`'s `mappend` across the dataset once.

There's probably a better way to write the `Monoid`s that would be faster.

I tried using the 'pipes' library, since it seemed appropriate for this problem, but I don't think it added anything to the solution.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Main (
    main
) where


import System.IO

import Data.Maybe
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Char
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

-- Min monoid
newtype Min a = Min {
    getMin :: Maybe a
} deriving (Show, Eq)

instance (Ord a) => Monoid (Min a) where
    mempty = Min Nothing
    mappend x y = Min $ ((liftM2 min) (getMin x) (getMin y)) <|>  (getMin x) <|> (getMin y)

toMin = Min . Just

-- Max monoid
newtype Max a = Max {
    getMax :: Maybe a
} deriving (Show, Eq)

instance (Ord a) => Monoid (Max a) where
    mempty = Max Nothing
    mappend x y = Max $  ((liftM2 max) (getMax x) (getMax y)) <|>  (getMax x) <|> (getMax y)

toMax = Max . Just       

-- Extrema monoid
type Extrema a = (Min a, Max a)

getMinimum = getMin . fst
getMaximum = getMax . snd

toExtrema x = (toMin x, toMax x)

-- Biggest drop monoid

data BiggestDrop a = BiggestDrop {
    extrema :: Extrema a,
    biggestDrop :: Max a
} deriving Show

instance (Num a, Ord a) => Monoid (BiggestDrop a) where
    mempty = BiggestDrop {
        extrema = mempty,
        biggestDrop = mempty
    }
    mappend before after = BiggestDrop {
        extrema = mappend (extrema before) (extrema after),
        biggestDrop = mconcat [
            biggestDrop before,
            biggestDrop after,
            Max $ (liftM2 (-)) (getMaximum $ extrema before) (getMinimum $ extrema after)
        ]
    }

toBiggestDrop x = BiggestDrop {
        extrema = toExtrema x,
        biggestDrop = mempty
    }

-- Read data from stdin and fold BiggestDrop's mappend across it

main = do
  (answer :: BiggestDrop Int) <- P.fold mappend mempty id (words >-> (P.map (toBiggestDrop . read)))
  print answer
  print . fromJust . getMax $ biggestDrop answer
  where
    words = stdinWords >-> (P.map C.unpack) >-> (P.filter ((/=) []))


-- Produce words from stdin

stdinWords' :: (MonadIO m) => Int -> Producer B.ByteString m ()
stdinWords' chunkSize = goMore B.empty
    where
        goMore remainder = do
            eof <- liftIO isEOF
            case eof of
                True ->
                    unless (B.null remainder) $ yield remainder                    
                _ -> do
                    chunk <- liftIO $ B.hGet stdin chunkSize
                    let (first:others) = C.splitWith isSpace chunk
                    goParts ((B.append remainder first):others)
        goParts parts = do
            case parts of
                [] ->
                    goMore B.empty
                [x] ->
                    goMore x
                (x:xs) -> do
                    unless (B.null x) $ yield x
                    goParts xs

stdinWords = stdinWords' 512
```

I put the above code together using the 'pipes' library, hoping to learn about 'pipes-bytestring'. I had to give up and write a producer to read the words from the file. The size of chunks to read from the file is just a guess.

Comment: Is that `mappend` for `BiggestDrop` really associative?

Comment: You might like the [monoids](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoids-0.3.2/docs/Data-Monoid-Ord.html) package.

Comment: I think the non-deprecated things like that monoids package are off in the semigroups package now (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups).

Comment: Yes, that `mappend` for `BiggestDrop` is associative. For `((a * b) * c)` the drop expands to `max (max ad bd (a2 - b1)) cd ((max a2 b2) - c1))`. Getting rid of nested `max`es leaves `max ad bd cd (a2 - b1) (a2 - c1) (b2 - c1)`. For `(a * (b * c))` it expands to, shuffled to be put in the same order `max ad bd cd (a2 - b1) (a2 - b1) (b2 - c1)`, which is identical. Surprisingly, it's associative without appealing to either `a1 <= a2` or `ad <= a2 - a1`. I expected the proof to require more.

Comment: Or they would be identical if I had typed the second one correctly. The second `(a2 - b1)` should be `(a2 - c1)`.  The second expression came from `max ad (max bd cd (b2 - c1)) (a2 - (min b1 c1))`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and effort to write this answer, unfortunately the pipes library is still a bit intimidating to me and I have no clue at all what you are doing here. I will most definitely come here and try to understand what you did here, after I have taken some time with the 'pipes' library, which I intended to do already some time ago.